# Why does Oracle claim java.util.Random.nextFloat() generates 2^24 possibilities and not 2^23?

Tags: java, random, floating-point

According to the documentation for [java.util.Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextFloat--), the Java class 
implements `nextFloat` by `next(24) / ((float)(1 << 24))` (ie. a random non-negative integer with 24 bits divided by 2<sup>24</sup>). The documentation claims that all 2<sup>24</sup> possible values can be returned. They are between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). However, I don't think that is true.

First, note that according to the IEC 559 (IEEE 754) standard, `float` has 23 fraction bits. But there is an implicit leading bit (to the left of the binary point) with value 1, unless the exponent is stored with all zeros. Therefore, it is true that there are a total of 2<sup>24</sup> values of type `float` that are between 0 (inclusive - not counting negative zero) and 1 (exclusive), but exactly half of these numbers are subnormal (all bits in the exponent are 0), which makes them all less than 2<sup>-126</sup>. Therefore, none of these numbers can be generated by the implementation. This is because they are all strictly smaller than 2<sup>-24</sup> which is used in the implementation.

The layout of `float` can be found at [Single-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

So what is it that I am missing?

Comment: it's a very good observation! why not generate random 32 bits and then control for non numerical values.

Comment: Possibly you confused `float` values that are represented by some value in the low 24 bits that encode them (with the upper eight bits zero) with the values that result of dividing 24 bits by 2\*\*24. All results of the latter are represntable in `float`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every number of type `float` has 23 fraction bits and 8 exponent bits. 
We show how to use `float` to precisely represent every number `n` of the form 0.b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>b<sub>3</sub>...b<sub>24</sub>. 
Let `i` be the smallest number such that  b<sub>i</sub>  is non-zero. 
If no such  `i`  exists then  `n=0`,  which can be represented in `float`. Otherwise, 
n = 2<sup>-i</sup>2<sup>i</sup>0.b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>b<sub>3</sub>... b<sub>24</sub>. 
The part  2<sup>-i</sup> can clearly be represented by the 8 bits 
of exponents in `float`. 
Furthermore, the part
2<sup>i</sup>0.b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>b<sub>3</sub>... b<sub>24</sub>
is of the form 1.b<sub>i+1</sub>b<sub>i+2</sub>...b<sub>24</sub> which has at most 23 fraction bits. 
Therefore, `n` can be precisely represented in `float`.

All that remains is to uniformly generate random integers of the form
b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>b<sub>3</sub>... b<sub>24</sub> and then divide them by 2<sup>24</sup> which is exactly what Oracle is suggesting.

Answer (score 5):

In the interval [+0, 1), there are 127•2<sup>23</sup> values representable in `float`, not 2<sup>24</sup>. There is one for each combination of an exponent encoding field from 0 to 126, inclusive, with each value of 23 bits in the significand encoding field.

Every value in the form *m*•2<sup>−24</sup>, with 0 ≤ *m* < 2<sup>24</sup>, is representable. The smallest non-zero value in this form is 2<sup>−24</sup>, which is represented with an exponent code of 103 and a significand code of 0. The mathematical exponent is the code, 103, minus the bias, 127, which equals −24, and the mathematical significand is 1.

For any such *m* other than zero, let *b* be the position number of its leading 1 bit (numbering from 0 for the low bit). Then *m*•2<sup>−24</sup> is encoded in `float` with an exponent code of *b*+103 and a significand code of *m*•2<sup>24− *b*</sup>−2<sup>24</sup>. For *m* = 0, it is encoded with all zero bits.

None of the numbers in this form are subnormal.